# Delete all cached files and refresh in one strike

Tags: ce-cache

Is it with Ce Cache possible to delete all cached files in one strike and have them immediately regenerated?

/David

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question you could use CE Cache's Clean tag {exp:ce_cache:clean} http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-cache/user-guide/tags .

To recreate all the cache I think you would need to trigger a crawler to go through your site, maybe based on your sitemap, or cron job that does the same.